# How to get the sum of each Month?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

A have a collection list that contains September ,October,November However i want to add specifically Each Month

```
Start Time                    EndTime
September 11,2016 5:00PM   September 11,2016 8:00PM  
September 12,2016 10:00AM  September 12,2016 8:00PM 
October 1,2016 5:00PM      September 11,2016 8:00PM  
October 2,2016 10:00AM     September 12,2016 8:00PM 
November 1,2016 5:00PM     November 11,2016 8:00PM  
November 2,2016 10:00AM    November 12,2016 8:00PM
```

My code

```
List<MonthHours> oList=new List<MonthHours>();
Int total=0;
TimeSpan span=new TimeSpan();
foreach(var data in oList)
{
Span=data.EndTime-data.StartTime;
Total+=span.hours;
}
```

I got all the sums From september to November , What i actually want is to get the sumb By Month Example In september i got 3 hours , int october 5 hours, in November 5 hours.

Sorry newbie TIA

Comment: is that arrange in a spreadsheet?

Comment: you can use linq to group by data.starttime.month and then sum up the timespans

Comment: It's a Property collection. Please help me with this

Comment: Exactly looking for the answer By using LINQ i dont know how to use it properly

Comment: Can you show us your HoursData class?

Comment: public class totalWorkHours
    {
        public totalWorkHours()
        {

        }
        public double totalperDay(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
        {
            try
            {
                TimeSpan hours = new TimeSpan();
                hours = date2 - date1;
                return hours.TotalHours;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Convert.ToDouble(null);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: public class MonthHours
    {
        #region Property
        private string _Month;
        private double _Hours;

        public string Month
        {
            get
            {
                return _Month;
            }

            set
            {
                _Month = value;
            }
        }

        public double Total_Hours
        {
            get
            {
                return _Hours;
            }

            set
            {
                _Hours = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion Property
    }

Comment: How can something start in october and end in september, the same year?

Comment: Also, for the intervals that start and end in different months, should they count for all involved months or only the start month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = oList
    .GroupBy(data => data.StartTime.ToString("MMMM"))
    .Select(g => new MonthHours {
        Month = g.Key,
        Total_Hours = g.Sum(d => (d.EndTime - d.StartTime).TotalHours)
    });

foreach (var month in result) {
    var str = string.Format("Month : {0}, Total Hours : {1}", month.Month, month.Total_Hours);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is G.KEY , what it does ? so that i can understand the code .

Comment: WOW thankyou so much my problem for almost a week has finally solved. Im a junior software developer thankyou so much . It's really a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Group By your List by date month
Then Select each summary of all differences

```
var grouped = oList.GroupBy(d=>StartTime.Month).Select(c=>c.Sum(d=>(d.EndTime-d.StartTime)).ToArray();
```